# How to Check What Are the Questions that Are Migrated Between the Sites

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there any way to use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to see the questions that are migrated between different sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for each site, you can find questions that have both been imported to and exported from it.

Start with this query, which shows all migration activity:

> ```
> SELECT *
>    FROM Posts p
>    INNER JOIN PostHistory ph ON ph.PostId = p.Id
>    WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 17
> ```